# Is there a way i can add multiple variables to one object?

Tags: java, object, methods

So I've been given the method below and I'm not allowed to change it. What I need is it to create a couple of objects with the variables below but keeps coming up with an error that says "The constructor menu(int, String, String) is undefined." Am I doing something wrong?

```
      import java.util.Scanner;
      import java.util.*;

      public class menu {

private static void addNewStudent() 
         {
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Please enter the correct details below");
     System.out.println("ID: "); 
     int userId = scanner.nextInt(); 

     System.out.println("First name: ");
     String userFirst = scanner.next();

     System.out.println("Last name: ");
     String userLast = scanner.next();

     System.out.println("English assignment 1 mark: ");
     int english1 = scanner.nextInt();

     System.out.println("English assignment 2 mark: ");
int english2 = scanner.nextInt();

     System.out.println("English assignment 3 mark: ");
     int english3 = scanner.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Math assignment 1 mark: ");
     int math1 = scanner.nextInt();

     System.out.println("Math assignment 2 mark: ");
     int math2 = scanner.nextInt();;

     System.out.println("Math assignment 3 mark: ");
     int math3 = scanner.nextInt();

     menu userStudentObj = new menu(userId, userFirst, userLast);
     menu userEnglishObj = new menu(english1, english2, english3);
     menu userMathObj = new menu(math1, math2, math3);


// Asks the user for the student information (ID, First, Last, Assignments)
// Then creates the appropriate objects and adds the students to the student list
```

I would expect to have created 3 new object that contain the user input variables within the objects if that makes sense.

Comment: Could you please add your object class code?

Comment: *The constructor menu(int, String, String) is undefined* means that your object class doesn't have constructor that match this Constructor parameters. So you need to create a constructor with the same arguments.

Comment: So there is no way around not changing the constructor? Ill have to add in the needed parameters?

Comment: Try something below. And I would recommend you to read about class design and how it improves performance, code quality and helps to provide better interaction with object.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you didn't specify any non default constructor, to create objects so compiler have no ideas what do you want to create if object is not specified for that. But there is another problem. Your object is designed in not the best way. So if you want to handle it correctly you could change your class design so you handle it in right way.

For example you could make it a bit different, like in this example (it's not perfect, it still can be more separate and better designed):

```
class User {
    int userId;
    String userFirstName;
    String userSecondName;

    private ArrayList<Integer> mathSums = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Integer> englishSums = new ArrayList<>();

    User(int userId, String userFirstName, String userSecondName) {
        this.userId = userId;
        this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
        this.userSecondName = userSecondName;
    }

    public void addMathSums(int mathSums) {
        this.mathSums.add(mathSums);
    }

    public void addEnglishSums(int englishSums) {
        this.englishSums.add(englishSums);
    }
}
```

So by the help of this class you could change the way, how you define and set the values for your object and it would look like that:

1) You define constructor with arguments so you're able to use it for object creation:

```
 User user = new User(userId, userFirst, userLast);
```

2) Then you can add sums into `ArrayList`s that are member variables (fields) in `User` class:

```
user.addMathSums(math1);
user.addMathSums(math2);
user.addMathSums(math3);
user.addEnglishSums(english1);
user.addEnglishSums(english2);
user.addEnglishSums(english3);
```

It could be performed in different ways using arrays, lists or other data structure, but you really need to pay attention for your class design. More time you spend on designing object less modifications you will need later.

3) You probably want to interact with this object so you need to get a reference for it somehow. You could change the method signature so you will "return" created object after you finish your input. So you need to make some changes:

On the method change the signature return type to User:

```
private static User addNewStudent() { ... }
```

Then add return for that and return created user:

```
private static User addNewStudent() {
    /* code */

    User user = new User(userId, userFirst, userLast);
    /* add sums */

    return user;
}
```

4) Use this method in your `main()`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    User createdUser = User.addNewStudent();
}
```